# Cannot check out from svn

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

When I try to check out from `svn`, it is showing this `alert`.

[image]

I am already using this `svn` link and working on this for the past couple of months.
I needed the same copy of project from `svn` in a new window for some other work.
But, when I try to checkout, it shows this alert.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue with android studio. Can't c heckout  svn :-(

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: i am also getting same problem. i was solved this by check out the svn project from eclipse and then import the project  from local directory to android studio. after then committed the new copy in separate svn location.

Comment: I updated the studio to new version just 2 days before to 1.3

Answer (score 0):

> i was solved this by check out the svn project from eclipse and then import the project from local directory to android studio. after then committed the new copy in separate svn location.

Based on the comment of @RamBabu Pudari I would assume, you could check out the project with another SVN client like TortoiseSVN or SlikSVN on Windows.

Then you are able to import it into your AndroidStudio. Does this workaround fix your problem?

It would be useful to know, if you can manage your SVN commits with Android Studio after importing it.

Comment: Thank you all for solutions. I have to check your solution.  But this is a work around fix right? This is a normal checking out process from svn, what is wrong happening here? We missed any settings?

Comment: Did you now check, wheter my solution worked or not?